# How to anticipate a changing multidimensional array and correlate all the data to the proper places

Tags: php, json, pdo

Okay I am pulling data from an api and it returns json objects. In this data there are 4 fields, lack of a better word, level , xp, rank, id. Level pertains to the level of a certain skill, rank pertains to the total rank in the skill compared to other players, xp pertains to total xp in the skill, and id pertains to the a certain skill. The way the api sorts data is highest xp to lowest xp and there are 27 skills total.  Okay now that I got that outta the way I am trying to connect the dots so to speak. Ex id 6, in the below array, is the skill magic and id 17 is the skill thieving. So, because the api sorts from highest xp to lowest, $array[skillvalues][0][id] will not always equal 6(magic). Then I wouldn't know how to connect the dots that all the values in $array[skillvalues][0], in this example, belongs to the magic skill. Meaning my level in magic is 99, my xp in magic is 32mil, my rank compared to other players is 56,731

This api pops out more data than the skills data... I was able to get it down to the data that I am interested in and that is about it. I got variables ready to go to store the values in the right place, I just need the parts that connect the dots. I have tried searching here an google for the answer and everything I come across doesn't solve the two issues I stated above. I was able to use foreach loops to target that id field, but I don't think that is what I need. I would appreciate any feedback.

```
Array
(
  [skillvalues] => Array
      (
         [0] => Array
             (
                [level] => 99
                [xp] => 322039589
                [rank] => 56731
                [id] => 6
             )

         .
         .
         .


         [26] => Array
             (
                [level] => 73
                [xp] => 10590542
                [rank] => 251597
                [id] => 17
             )

     )
     //skill ids if it matters
     AttacK: 0
     Defence: 1
     Strength: 2
     Hitpoints: 3
     Ranged: 4
     Prayer: 5
     Magic: 6
     Cooking: 7
     Woodcutting: 8
     Fletching: 9
     Fishing: 10
     Firemaking: 11
     Crafting: 12
     Smithing: 13
     Mining: 14
     Herblore: 15
     Agility: 16
     Thieving: 17
     Slayer: 18
     Farming: 19
     Runecrafting: 20
     Hunter: 21
     Construction: 22
     Summoning: 23
     Dungeoneering: 24
     Divination: 25
     Invention: 26
```

Comment: Are you trying to link ID to Skill eg. 6 = magic?

Comment: correct, sorry I thought I explained it well it enough

Comment: You can just create an array of the skills (either in PHP array or place them in a DB whatever you prefer). Ill give you an example below of PHP arrays which is the easiest to get started with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place all the skills in an array using the skill ID as the Key. If you called the array like `echo $skills_arr[1]` Defense would be echoed. You could also place these in a Database and call them depending on your preferences, how many skills there actually were etc.

```
$skills_arr = array(
    '1' => 'Defence',
    '2' => 'Strength',
    '3' => 'Hitpoints',
    '4' => 'Ranged',
    '5' => 'Prayer',
    '6' => 'Magic',
    '7' => 'Cooking'
);
//etc


foreach($array[skillvalues] as $skills){
    echo 'Skill Type:'.$skills_arr[$skills['id']];
    echo 'Skill XP:'.$skills['xp'];
    echo 'Skill Rank:'.$skills['rank'];
    echo 'Skill Level:'.$skills['level'];
}
```

Comment: This is amazing!!!! I Thank you so much!!!! Now only issue is the way the database is setup, it wouldn't support this way. Right now the db is setup for variables like $magic_xp, $magic_rank, $magic_level. How would I need to change the database to make this work. I amm sooooooo sorry I should've mentioned this in my question

Comment: Would need to see how the db is structured to give a proper answer. If this question is solved just start a new one :)

Comment: Your right the question was answered. Umm I cant paste my whole db structure as its over 82 columns

Comment: Jesus have mercy lol Don't have to show all of them but if you can give an idea of how is structured and maybe a screenshot of how the columns are structured, you might be able to get some help. Head over to code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ they can help you create more efficient code.

Answer (score 0):

TO any future readers please disregard my questions about the database because Second2None's code seperates everything!! I thank you sooooo much second you are a lifesaver!!!!

all you need to do is.....

```
$skills_arr = array(
 '0'  => "Attack",     
 '1'  => "Defence",      
 '2'  => "Strength",     
 '3'  => "Hitpoints",    
 '4'  => "Ranged",       
 '5'  => "Prayer",       
 '6'  => "Magic",        
 '7'  => "Cooking",      
 '8'  => "Woodcutting",  
 '9'  => "Fletching",    
 '10' => "Fishing",      
 '11' => "Firemaking",   
 '12' => "Crafting",     
 '13' => "Smithing",     
 '14' => "Mining",       
 '15' => "Herblore",     
 '16' => "Agility",      
 '17' => "Thieving",     
 '18' => "Slayer",       
 '19' => "Farming",      
 '20' => "Runecrafting", 
 '21' => "Hunter",       
 '22' => "Construction", 
 '23' => "Summoning",    
 '24' => "Dungeoneering",
 '25' => "Divination",   
 '26' => "Invention"    
);
foreach($highscores[skillvalues] as $skills){
  $skill = $skills_arr[$skills['id']];
  $xp = $skills['xp'];
  $rank = $skills['rank'];
  $level = $skills['level'];
  if($skill == "Slayer"){ 
   echo "My level in " . $skill . " is " . $level . " and I 
   have a total of " . $xp . " xp";//this is outputing all the info for slayer skill
  }

}
```